# Why is Mathematica exporting a very large gif?

Tags: plotting, export

I am trying to export a GIF using Mathematica. Several other GIFs are about 2-3MB large. But the following one generates a whopping 70MB GIF, even though it is not extremely complicated.

Any suggestions on working around this?

````
tubesz=0.02;
arrowsz=0.04;
bgcol=None;

x[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Cos[u]
y[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Sin[u]
z[u_, v_] := (v/2) Sin[u/2]

circlepts = 
  Table[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, {\[Theta], 0, 
    2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/100}];

g1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Tube[circlepts, tubesz]}];

m = Table[Show[g1,
    Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[arrowsz], 
      Arrow[Tube[{{x[0, 0], y[0, 0], z[0, 0]}, {x[0, 0.9], y[0, 0.9], 
          z[0, 0.9]}}, tubesz]]}], 
    Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[arrowsz], 
      Arrow[Tube[{{x[\[Theta], 0], y[\[Theta], 0], 
          z[\[Theta], 0]}, {x[\[Theta], 0.9], y[\[Theta], 0.9], 
          z[\[Theta], 0.9]}}, tubesz]]}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 0, 
      2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 3]}, 
     Mesh -> {8, 3}, PlotPoints -> {50, 2}], Background -> bgcol, 
    ImageSize -> 1000, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> None], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/100}];

Export["mypath\\mobius_parallel_transport.gif", m, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 0.02,"AnimationRepetitions"->1]
```
````

Comment: you do not have `tubesz` defined. you do not have `arrowsz` defined.  you do not have `bgcol` defined.

Comment: Edited, thanks for noting that.

Comment: evaluating `g1` now gives plot error. May because `r` is not defined.

Comment: @MohitKumar, try to use `Line` instead of `Tube`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing `Specularity[White,3]` the size of the gif file reduces by 50% on windows 10 using V 14

[image]

You could play around more with options to see if you can reduce it more, but I remembered that `Specularity` can cause the gif size to become large.

code

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
tubesz = 0.02;
arrowsz = 0.04;
bgcol = None;
x[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Cos[u]
y[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Sin[u]
z[u_, v_] := (v/2) Sin[u/2]

r = 1; (*was missing *)
circlepts = Table[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], 0}, {θ, 0, 2 π, π/100}];
g1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Tube[circlepts, tubesz]}]

m = Table[
   Show[g1, 
    Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[arrowsz], 
      Arrow[Tube[{{x[0, 0], y[0, 0], z[0, 0]}, {x[0, 0.9], y[0, 0.9], 
          z[0, 0.9]}}, tubesz]]}], 
    Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[arrowsz], 
      Arrow[Tube[{{x[θ, 0], y[θ, 0], 
          z[θ, 0]}, {x[θ, 0.9], y[θ, 0.9], 
          z[θ, 0.9]}}, tubesz]]}], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 0, 
      2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, 
     Mesh -> {8, 3}, PlotPoints -> {50, 2}], Background -> bgcol, 
    ImageSize -> 1000, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> None], {θ, 0, 2 π, π/100}];

Export["mobius_parallel_transport.gif", m, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 0.02, "AnimationRepetitions" -> 1]
```